# when to use "_(.)" kind of things in python.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

for example , what is "_make" in python. Where in the python documentation I can find the definition for the same . Also how many such type of **_(.)**  are there in python.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Sorry for doing so, the system was not allowing me to put it straight . My question is what and when we use "_make" in python .

Comment: `_something` in classes are private members that get mangled,see dupe. `_` in `for _ in range(20):` are named like that because they are not important and `_hello = "something"` in functions are bad style, stemming from c/c++ where some ages ago they signified private members (by naming convention).

Comment: lastly, double `_` before and after method names are so called dunder methods: see [llist-of-all-python-dunder-methods-which-ones-do-you-need-to-implement-to-corre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238263/list-of-all-python-dunder-methods-which-ones-do-you-need-to-implement-to-corre) and research the current documentation